# Spring MVC Session: Expected Session attribute 'user', which already there in Session

Tags: spring, session

I am facing

```
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute "Money"
```

Following are series of steps:

1) User gets a page from controller: Finance/MoneyCreation

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Finance/*")
@SessionAttributes({ "Money", "MoneyForm"})
public class MoneyController {


  @RequestMapping(value = "MoneyCreation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String openMoneyLandingPage(@ModelAttribute("Money") Money money,
   Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("MoneyForm", form);
   return "/okonomi/okonomiregister";
}
```

In above controller, the session attribute Money is not set somewhere else (is that required?. Now from UI i have have to open a dialogue on button click which executes following:

AjaxController: finance/create/money

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Finance/*")
@SessionAttributes({ "Money", "MoneyForm" })
public class AjaxMoneyController{

@RequestMapping(value = "create/money", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String openDialogBox(@ModelAttribute("Money") User user, Model  model) {

return "/commonProcess/dialog/MoneyDialog";
}
```

On click of button; i am facing:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute "Money"
```

Do i need to set Money somewhere else?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In UI, i have added conv id and this issue get resolved.

```
var convId = $('#formId').find('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val();
```

Comment: This is certainly not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put the attribute into the http session before referring to it.

Quoting the very good Spring docs (you ought to look into, too!), you see an example reading

```
if (!model.containsAttribute("site")) {
    model.addAttribute("site", new PetSite());
}
```

"site" being a SessionAttribute (like "money" in your case).

Comment: So i will do this is MoneyController ? Trying it

Comment: I have now added this code in openMoneyLandingPage() -> if (!model.containsAttribute("bruker")) {
        System.out.println("Added Bruker");
        model.addAttribute("bruker", bruker); .......... but it does not work.
    }

Comment: Well, it is hard to tell what to do in your case, besides mentioning the excellent Spring documentation, because (at least for me) it is hard to get a good picture of the things you are trying to achieve. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the object into session before using it. The standard way is to use a `@ModelAttribute` *method*:

```
@ModelAttribute("Money")
Money getMoney() {
  return new Money(); //or however you create a default
}
```

`getMoney()` will get called before every request.